# Сonvert JSON array to List<T> error

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to write this converter to work with all types. So I'm using generics. But receive the following compile-time error.

> Couldn't convert array to list
>   [System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

I'm not sure why its saying I'm converting a array to a list, when it should be adding an element to a list. Or how I can cast it.

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T> (JsonData dataArray)
{
    List<T> dataList = new List<T> ();

    if(dataArray.IsArray)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < dataArray.Count; i++)
        {
            dataList.Add ((T)(object)dataArray[i]);
        }
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: What type `dataArray[i]` is?

Comment: It is obvious. What you have in `dataArray[i]` is not of type `T`

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the JsonData are not of whatever your type T is that you are passing in.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are casting to `object` and then casting to `T`.  If dataArray[i] can be cast to `T` then you shouldn't need to go through `object` to get there.  With that said, I would also cast by using `as` instead of a direct cast.  This is because it doesn't seem as if you will always know that `dataArray[i]` can be cast to `T`.

```
var item = dataArray[i] as T;
if (item != null)
{
    dataList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: 'as' only works for reference types and I need to potentially accept both. JsonData objects can't be cast to T directly.